# How does Keras calculate model accuracy in each epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I am training a multi-label image classifier using transfer learning in Keras. During training I asked the model to report out loss and acc in each epoch. In the very last epoch, it says the training acc is ~86% and val acc is pretty much the same. However, when I took the trained model and test on the training data using Sklearn performance matrix, it says the accuracy is 97%.
I am not sure if I am doing some thing wrong or the way of calculating accuracy is different in Keras and Sklearn. Please help

Comment: The training metrics are calculating for each batch during the epoch. Between the first and last batch, the model has had nearly an entire epoch worth of training. Basically, the training metrics are (on average) about half an epoch behind.

Comment: Thanks@Swier. I understand there could be difference between the epoch acc than the sklearn acc. However, the fact is the acc of training has been staying at ~85% for several epoch and therefore I stopped the training and saved the model. When I used the saved model in sklearn performance matrix, it gave 97% acc on the same training data. I don't understand how the difference can be this large.